# PHP log out with AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a logout function that looks like this.

> ```
> if ($_GET["argument"]=='logOut'){
>     if(session_id() == '') {
>         session_start();
>     }
>     session_unset();
>     session_destroy();
>     $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
>     $extra = 'index.php';
>     header("Location: http://$host/$extra");
>     exit; 
> }
> ```

My problem is that, If I inspect the page and look at the `Network` preview and response, it looks 'fine'.

There are two php files listed that was processed.

`http://localhost:5000/inc/mainScripts.php?argument=logOut`

which is where the function is located.

and `http://localhost:5000/index.php`

Which is where i would like to be redirected.

The `Response` tab in the `Network` of the inspect page area in chrome
contains the full login html page `login.php` but in the browser it remains in the same place. Like the `header` command has never been called.

What Am I doing wrong?

**HTML AJAX call to this function:**

> ```
>         $("#logout_btn").click(function() {
>             $.ajax({
>                 url: './inc/mainScripts.php?argument=logOut'
>             })
>         });
> ```

---

### **SOLUTION**

***AJAX***

> ```
>         $("#logout_btn").click(function() {
>             $.ajax({
>                 url: './inc/mainScripts.php?argument=logOut',
>                 success: function(data){
>                     window.location.href = data;
>                 }
>             });
>         });
> ```

***PHP***

> ```
> if ($_GET["argument"]=='logOut'){
>     if(session_id() == '') {
>         session_start();
>     }
>     session_unset();
>     session_destroy();
>     $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
>     $link = "http://$host/index.php";
>     echo $link; 
> }
> ```

Comment: what is `$extra` when you use it?

Comment: What do you mean. its `'index.php'`

Comment: ok so I am a little confused, are you saying the browser is reporting it as `index.php` when you expected it to show `login.php` or the browser is still reporting it as `mainScripts.php?argument=logOut` when it should be `index.php`?

Comment: Browser shows `http://localhost:5000/Main.php` main content page.
but inspecting the page the `network` tab shows php calling the function and then showing `index.php` but nothing changes on the browser. I will append a image

Comment: Show the HTML of the logout link/button. It sounds like you're doing the logout as an AJAX call.

Comment: Yes, I am using AJAX. is that a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
if( isset($_GET['argument']) && $_GET['argument'] == 'logOut' && !empty( session_id() ) ) {

    session_destroy();
    header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/index.php");
    exit;

}
```

Edit: If you're using AJAX, it'd be easier to send the url from your php script back to your javascript and redirect from there.

Comment: Yes, the **EDIT** section *redirect with jquery* worked. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are probably running into the same common problem that many people run into when people first start to program in PHP.

Calls to `header()` only works when there are NO previous HTML output generated. If there are any HTML output generated, even just a single space, calls to `header()` will fail. To get around this problem, use functions such as `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()`.